# Processing Escapes using the Spirit Parser Framework

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I'm trying to parse a string similar to the following using a spirit parser:

`<junk> -somearg#this is a string with a literal ## in it# <junk>`

What I'm looking for is a grammar which can extract the portion inside the # marks, but is smart to skip over the double ## in the middle, which is an escape meaning a literal #.

This was what I had in mind:
`confix_p(L'#', *anychar_p, L'#' >> ~ch_p(L'#'))`
However this returns:
`#this is a string with a literal ##`
I'd like it to skip over the `##` characters .... is this possible?

Billy3

Comment: +1 because I didn't know about the Spirit Parser Framework till now. Reading the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding a kleene star to the confix parser. Thanks anyway!

`*confix_p(L'#', *anychar_p, L'#' >> ~ch_p(L'#'))` works as expected.